# Lethal force to prevent virus outbreak?

Tags: criminal-law, self-defense, homicide

Lets say im in the hostpital or a supermarket. and somone just died from somthing unknow, what seems to be a virus or any other transmissible disease. am i in legal right to use letal force to prevent someone from leaving the erea. we propably have all seen that cenario in a movie so i wonder, would i be in my legal rights to stop someone from going outside and spread it?..

Comment: Related (even if it might be a little outdated) in the sense of killing someone for the greater good: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_v_Dudley_and_Stephens

Comment: Only if you're the red queen.

Answer (score 2):

No.

- You have no idea whether this person is even likely to be infected by anything whatsoever.
- Second, even if you did know they were infected, *you* are not facing an immediate threat of violence.
- Third, even if you knew this person were infected, *and* they began to approach you, *and* that was deemed an immediate threat of violence (it wouldn't be), you would have less forceful alternatives available to you.

You can't unilaterally decide to implement a quarantine and enforce it with deadly force. Even for those *with* the power to establish quarantines, their enforcement tools are fines and imprisonment. ([CDC: Legal Authorities for Isolation and Quarantine](https://www.cdc.gov/quarantine/aboutlawsregulationsquarantineisolation.html))